# Replace <ul> and <li> with <tr> and <td>

Tags: html, css, html-table, slider, html-lists

I am working on a platform where no Javascript or ul and li tags are allowed. And I want to do a pure CSS3 slider. How do I replace the ul and li tags from this code with tr and td so to have a functional slider? I found out that simply replacing them is not working. Is it possible to replace them?

The initial working slider with ul and li: http://jsfiddle.net/CLLNH/

```
<ul>
<li>
</li>
</ul>
```

The code with replacement but not working: http://jsfiddle.net/E5WA2/

```
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Create a dynamic table container `<table></table>` and then replace `<ul>`, `<li>` with `<tr>`, `<td>` and place it inside table container.

Comment: Thank you. stupid mistake from my part. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are missing the `table` tag.

Answer (score 3):

You know `TR` and `TD` are elements part of `TABLE`, right? Just wrap the markup in a table and you should be on the right track:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E5WA2/1/